# Alter cor da célula da DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Tenho um DataGrid em C# WPF, e preciso mudar a cor de algumas células de acordo com uma condição. Por exemplo tenho a coluna Estoque e caso o Estoque seja menor que um valor especifico eu coloco a cor dele em vermelho. como posso fazer isso, recuperar a cor da celular e atribuir uma nova cor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom como não tem contexto vou propor um exemplo minimo, funcionando da seguinte forma, se o campo `Stock` da classe `Data` for **0** a sua célula vai alterar a cor de fundo (`Background`) para vermelho.

***Exemplo minimo***

***Classe:***

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
}
```

***WPF***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350"
        Width="399.702" Initialized="Window_Initialized">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
               AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="291"
               Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Width="369" CanUserReorderColumns="False"
               CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"
                    Header="Id" Width="50" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"
                    Header="Name" Width="250" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Stock}"
                    Header="Stock" Width="50" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Stock}" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="Background">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>            
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>    
</Window>
```

Ao preencher a lista de informações da classe `Data` e passar isso ao `DataGrid` na coluna Stock terá as seguintes marcação:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Stock}"
        Header="Stock" Width="50" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Stock}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

nessa marcação existe `DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle` com `Style.Triggers`que é responsável em verificar essa condição.

---

Em codificação também daria, seguindo o mesmo ***exemplo minimo***:

```
private void DataGrid_Color(DataGrid grid)
{
    foreach(Data item in grid.ItemsSource)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item.Stock == 0)
            {
                DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator
                                                   .ContainerFromItem(item);

                DataGridCell column = grid.Columns[2].GetCellContent(row)
                                                     .Parent as DataGridCell;
                if (row != null)
                {
                    column.Background = Brushes.Red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

e chame esse método assim:

```
DataGrid_Color(Grid);
```

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [WPF DataGrid cell style from different property in XAML - SO<sub>En</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36486236/6797930)
- [How to change single cell color of datagrid in wpf? - SO<sub>En</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189717/how-to-change-single-cell-color-of-datagrid-in-wpf)

Comment: Consegui entender seu exemplo e funcionou perfeitamente, mas supondo, é possível acessar a cell pelo código e adicionar um novo backgroud para ela? por exemplo, uma função no meu código fonte que vai ler todas as cell da minha grid, e de acordo com o dado encontrado nessa celular ele decide se vai ou não alterar sua cor! é possivel fazer isso?

Comment: Se fica mais fácil o entendimento https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208319/alterando-cor-de-cell-de-acordo-com-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-if-em-c%C3%B3digo-fonte-c-wpf

Comment: @BrunoSilva tem sim, é só fazer um `foreach` no `DataGrid`, vou também adicionar isso na resposta, e por favor se for útil aceite como resposta da sua pergunta ( só lembrando que isso não tinha como dado na sua pergunta e por isso a proposta inicial foi a primeira solução )

Comment: Entendi, obrigado por me ajudar a resolver o problema! sua resposta me ajudou bastante.