# Alterando Cor de Cell de acordo com condição no IF em código fonte C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Tenho um DataGrid em um form em C# WPF, como é possível executar um método recupera cada cell contida nesse DataGrid e atribuir um possível valor, ou alterar a cor do background?

Por exemplo tenho um DataGrid:

```
[ A ] [ D ] [ C ] [ C ]
[ B ] [ A ] [ B ] [ A ]
[ C ] [ A ] [ B ] [ D ]
```

E então quero fazer um laço de repetição:

```
for (i<TamanhoDeLinhas) // Andar Linha
  for(j<TamanhodeColunas) // Andar Coluna
     if(DataGrid[i][j].Conteudo == A)
       DataGrid[i][j].BackGround = Color.Red;
```

É possível fazer isso?

Ou então, eu tenho os valores correspondentes de I J, ou seja eu sei em qual posição os valores vão estar!
Tenho que alterar o background da cell na Linha i=2 e j=3.
Como é possível fazer isso? Recupera a cell e atribuir uma nova cor de acordo com sua posição ou lendo uma por uma?

O DataGrid em questão está vinculado a um DataTable e ele gera as colunas e linhas de forma automática, no caso ele é dinâmico. então eu faço DataGrid.SourceItems = DataTable.DefaultView ... E assim jogo todos os itens para o DataGrid.

Qualquer uma das soluções é valida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você souber os índices, fiz esse teste:

```
public DataGridCell GetCell(DataGridCellInfo cellInfo)
{
  var cellContent = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
  if (cellContent != null)
     return (DataGridCell)cellContent.Parent;
  return null;
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var cellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(gd.Items[0], gd.Columns[2]);
  var cell = GetCell(cellInfo);
  cell.Background = Brushes.Red;
}
```

Entendendo que, no loaded da window você já tenha atribuído os valores a sua grid.

Comment: Eu tenho um DataTable, onde ele faz vinculação com o DataGrid e ele gera as colunas e linhas de forma automatica, no caso ele é dinamico. então eu faço DataGrid.SourceItems = DataTable.DefaultView ... E assim jogo todos os itens para o DataGrid. Quando utilizo esse método que você me mandou aparece a mensagem de erro "O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção."

Comment: No caso a minha tabela em questão é 4 por 4 e como no exemplo que mandou é 0|2 teria que ter dado certo

Comment: Adiciona a sua pergunta a parte do código onde você atribui o dataContext da grid ou os ítens, por gentileza. Essa mensagem parece ocorrer pq voce ainda não tem os ítems na grid.

Comment: certo, mas por exemplo, eu faço a vinculação dos itens a Grid e criei um button chamado atualiza, então após os dados aparecerem na grid eu chamo o evento click do button atualiza, e mesmo assim aparece esse erro!

Comment: Então, posso sugerir que tu faça: gd.UpdateLayout(); após a atribuição dos valores. Mas, para ajudarmos, tu vai precisar mostrar o código de atribuição e o código aonde dispara o evento pra obter as cells.

Comment: Coloquei o update em outro local e deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda! resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Crie uma extensão. Por exemplo, `DataGridExtensions.cs`:

```
public static class DataGridExtensions
{
    public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid,  DataGridRow linha, int indiceColuna = 0)
    {
        if (linha == null) return null;

        var presenter = linha.FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>();
        if (presenter == null) return null;

        var cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(indiceColuna);
        if (cell != null) return cell;

        grid.ScrollIntoView(linha, grid.Columns[indiceColuna]);
        cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(indiceColuna);

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Recupere a célula:

```
var cell = meuDataGrid.GetCell(linha, indiceColuna);
```

Utilizando o tipo correto da cor, ambos os casos funcionarão. `WPF Background` é do tipo [`System.Windows.Media.Brush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush(v=vs.110).aspx).

Exemplos de uso com a célula recuperada:

```
// using System.Windows.Media;

cell.Background = Brushes.White;
cell.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.White);
cell.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0, 0));
cell.Background = System.Windows.SystemColors.MenuHighlightBrush;
```

Comment: Isso vai mudar a cor de todo o DataGrid eu quero alterar o background de algumas células apenas

Comment: @BrunoSilva atualizei a resposta

Comment: Obrigado @mercador vou entender e implementa-lá agora! mas aparentemente está dando erro ao executar essa parte "FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>"

Comment: @BrunoSilva veja essa resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/25229554/3551913

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, ajudou bastante